# Angular 4 - On button click want to append textarea to view dynamically for each button click

Tags: html, ionic3, textarea, angular6, angular4-forms

Actually I want to create one textarea on button click over view. I don't have much idea in angular 4. Requirement is that on each click of button I want to create textarea over view. There should be multiple textarea's with cross buttons so I can remove the textarea if don't want.

Unfortunately I didn't try any code yet and didn't found any solution to implement it. But that is my requirement to create in angular 4. Any help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code will serve your requirement of generating textarea on button click as well as removing specific textarea.

```
<div style="padding-top: 200px">
<button (click)="addTextarea()">Add Textarea</button>
<form>
    <div *ngFor="let textarea of textAreasList; let textarea_index= index">
        <textarea name="{{textarea}}"></textarea>
        <button (click)="removeTextArea(textarea_index)">Remove</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

place the above code in .html file.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent {

    textAreasList:any = [];

    addTextarea(){        
        this.textAreasList.push('text_area'+ (this.textAreasList.length + 1));
    }


    removeTextArea(index){
        this.textAreasList.splice(index, 1);
    }

}
```

place the above code in .ts file. Let me know if you have any other difficulties.

Comment: Just one more question how can I make it draggable?

Comment: Can you please be little clear about what you want to do ? do you want ability to drag and drop textarea at some other place on page ?

Comment: yes.. right. I want to drag and drop textarea any where on the screen

Comment: For that functionality you can use 3rd party packages. Please create separate question for more help regarding drag and drop.

Comment: @UmangPatel If I want to display a tex area before adding one using add button how can I do that ?